# guestlist[j].getName() doesn't return name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to modify a script I found online by daubejb to create a Google Doc from a Google Calendar event.

The reference on Google's website says that the getName() command should display the name of the guest or it's email if a name is not available. However, nothing is displayed when I try. When I use the getEmail() command instead I get the Email just fine but I would prefer to get the name.

```
function createMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod() {

 //------VARIABLES--
 // define a custom style for all data labels
 var labelStyle ={};
 labelStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
 labelStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;

 // get today's date
 var today = new Date();

 // create a formatted version of today's date
 var formatted_today = Utilities.formatDate(today, "EDT","yyyy-MM-dd");   

 // number of hours from now to check for meetings
 var hours = 2

 // create variable for now
 var now = new Date();

 // create variable for number of hours from now in milliseconds
 var period_from_now = new Date(now.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));

 //------GET EVENTS/ATTRIBUTES FOR TIME PERIOD FROM NOW--------------
 // retrieve all calendar events for time period
 var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, period_from_now, {search: '@notes'}) ;

 // loop through each event an get meeting attributes, 
 for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
   var title = events[i].getTitle();
   var description = events[i].getDescription();
   var eventstart = events[i].getStartTime();
   var eventend = events[i].getEndTime();
   var location = events[i].getLocation();
   var owner = events[i].getCreators();
   var guestlist = events[i].getGuestList();

   //----------CREATE MEETING NOTE DOC -------------  
   // create a google doc with the meeting name as the title
   var file_exists = DriveApp.getFilesByName(title).hasNext();

   // check to see if file already exists, if does skip if loop
   if ((file_exists == false) && (guestlist.length >= 1)) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.create(title);

    // loop through event guests and get their emails and status
    for (var j=0;j<guestlist.length;j++) {
      var name = guestlist[j].getName();
      var guestStatus = guestlist[j].getGuestStatus();
      doc.getBody().appendParagraph(name + ': ' + guestStatus);
    }

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, 'Invités:\n')
    .setAttributes(0, 9, labelStyle);

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, 'Description:' + '\n\n' + description + '\n\n')
    .setAttributes(0, 11, labelStyle);

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, 'Organisateur:  ' + owner + '\n\n' )
    .setAttributes(0, 11, labelStyle);

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, 'Location:  ' + location + '\n\n')
    .setAttributes(0, 8, labelStyle);

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, 'Fin:  ' + eventend + '\n\n')
    .setAttributes(0, 3, labelStyle);

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, 'Début:  ' + eventstart + '\n')
    .setAttributes(0, 5, labelStyle);

    doc.getBody().editAsText()
    .insertText(0, title + '\n\n')
    .setFontSize(0, title.length, 14)
    .setBold(0, title.length, true)
    .setForegroundColor(0, title.length, '#cc0000');

   }  // if for file exists

  }  // for loop for each event 

}  // functionCreateMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getEmail()) is working, it only means that no name was provided hence [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getname) returns no results. The API is working fine.

I recommend trying this with your other calendars with valid guest names to see if your still getting no results.

Comment: I tried what you said and effectively, my name appears just fine on my personal email but the names of everyone at my workspace is unreadable. I just don't know what setting is missing. I looked into the  "about me" section in "My Account" on Google and I can't change anything without consulting an Admin so maybe that is the problem.